# Dagger2 how to perform constructor injection of a default constructor

Tags: android, dagger-2

Here is a scenario. Let's say there is a class A

```
Class A{

@Inject
public A(){}

}
```

And in my Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Inject
    A a;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

How to inject a in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok first of all you need a module:

```
@Module
class SomeModule{
  @SomeScope
  @Provides
  A proivdeTheAInstance(){
   return new A();
  }
}
```

Then your component:

```
@SomeScope
@Component(modules = {A.class}, dependencies={HigherLowerDependencyComponent.class})
interface SomeComponent{
 void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

After that in your activity, after you have performed build, in the `onCreate`

```
DaggerSomeComponent.builder().higherLowerDependencnyComponent(implementationHere).build().inject(this)
```

Than you can `@Inject A`

But there is one problem. Constructor injection doesn't work like that. In order to perform Constructor Injection, your `A()` constructor should have at least one dependency. The `@Inject` annotation on that constructor doesn't call the `A()` but its dependencies, which in your case would be 0, thus making the `@Inject` in your `A()` constructor unnecessary. Your question would stand if your `A` constructor would be like this:

```
    @Inject
    public A(SomeDependency dependency){
     this.someDependency = dependency;
    }
```

`SomeDependency` is going to be provided in the module as well:

```
@Module
class SomeModule{
  @SomeScope
  @Provides
  A proivdeTheAInstance(SomeDependency someDependency){ //now dagger will look to find this one
   return new A();
  }

@SomeScope
  @Provides
  SomeDependency proivdeSomeDependencyInstance(){ //which is provided here 
   return new SomeDependency();
  }
}
```

And you are good to go as you were:

```
class A{
private SomeDependency someDependency;
 @Inject
 public A(SomeDependency someDependency){ //the inject will require the SomeDependency
  this.someDependency = someDependency;
  }
}
```

EDIT: 
If dagger already knows how to provide the instance there is no need for a Module, you can just perform `@Inject` above the constructor of the class `A()`:

```
class A{
    @Inject
    public A(){
    }
}
```

Comment: So you meant to say that I shouldn't be using dagger for classes with only default constructor (no-args).

Comment: No that is not necessary, you are one step ahead. the constructor is the entry point for a class and if you inject in the main activity that would be enough because thats what brings you the constructor

Comment: Don't you think the code I would write for a no-args constructor is boilerplate  (module, component). Which I should avoid?

Comment: if you have only class `A()` then there is too much don't use dagger at all. Yes it's true, is a lot boilerplate if you use it only for 1 dependency. But if you project is huge,  and have lots like `A` classes, use it

Comment: Okay thanks a lot mate for all the useful information and your answer.